# How to look up objects with multiple attributes within an Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class that has a constructor as the following:

```
public Stock(String symbol, String name, int value) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}
```

Now, I have another class that is an abstract data type:

```
public class Holding {
    private Stock stock;
    private int amount;

    public Holding() {
        this.stock = null;
        this.amount = 0;
    }

    public Holding(Stock stock, int amount) {
        this.stock = stock;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Now, I am writing a method in another class.

I have created an arraylist using the Holding class above.
in this class

```
private ArrayList<Holding> holdings;
```

Now, I know that my objects in the Holding class contains a stock object, and an int amount.

How can I access only the symbol in my stock object in the `Holding` ArrayList?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean.

```
for (Holding h : holdings) {
    out.println(h.getStock().getSymbol());
}
```

That's assuming you have appropriate getters.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. But, I do have an idea now after seeing your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: @Santyurou No problem :) Make sure to include things like whether or not there are getters/setters, or public properties, etc. to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use Java's `foreach` to loop through the ArrayList:

```
for (Holding currentHolding : holdings) {
  System.out.println(currentHolding.stock.symbol); // prints out all the symbols
}
```

You need to change the attribute Stock from private to public, or create a getStock method to return it. Otherwise, since it is private, you can't access it.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ just noticed that, an odd combo of Holding keeping variables private (with no getters/setters) and Stocks being directly accessible

Comment: Well, we don't know if Stocks are directly accessible.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Since it is a public class and its properties were not set as private, they should be. Oh I see, you meant instances of Stocks. Right, just from what we see here, then no

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access only the symbol in my stock object in the Holding ArrayList?

With the code as given, you can't do this.

- You need to add a public getter method for the `stock` field of the `Holding` class.
- You (may) need to add a public getter method for the `symbol` field of the `Stock` class.

When you have done that you can do something like this:

```
public Holding getHoldingForSymbol(List<Holding> holdings, String symbol) {
    for (Holding h : holdings) {
        if (h.getStock().getSymbol().equals(symbol)) {
            return h;
        }
    }
    return null;  // or throw an exception
}
```